# PowerShell form Show(), ShowDialog() and System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar

Tags: winforms, progress-bar, powershell-3.0, show, showdialog

I have a PowerShell script that monitors progress using the `System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar` control.  I basically:

- Show the form
- Do some looping until a file exists
- Close the form

Because of the sequencing of events (i.e, I need to show the form and then do some processing afterwards) I cannot use `ShowDialog()` to show my form since it halts execution.  To circumvent this I use just `Show()`.

However, if I use `Show()` I see the progress bar grey background, but I don't see the actual progress bar itself!  If I use `ShowDialog()` I see all of the progress bar, but obviously my script logic won't execute.

As an example, change `Show()` for `ShowDialog()` below:

```bsh
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$waitForm = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
$waitForm.ClientSize = '502, 103'

$Progressbar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$Progressbar.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(5, 5)
$Progressbar.Width = 350
$Progressbar.Height = 15
$Progressbar.Style  = [System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle]::Continuous
$Progressbar.Value = 50
$waitForm.Controls.Add($Progressbar)

$waitForm.Show($this)

Start-Sleep -Seconds 3

$waitForm.Close()
```

Comment: This chap provides an interesting workaround.....I'm investigating it further: https://hinchley.net/articles/creating-a-windows-form-using-powershell-runspaces/